# Wifi-Disabled: Ubuntu 19.10 - Intel Wireless 7265

Tags: networking, drivers, iwlwifi, 19.10

After updating to Ubuntu 19.10:

[image]

Clicking *Continue using..* get resetted back to *Do not use..*.

Tried to download drivers from the Microsoft website and put them into `lib/firmware`.

The WiFi works though.

What is the correct work-around to make sure correct driver is used?

---

```
rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 59)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5110]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

```
ls -al /lib/firmware | grep 7265
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  736844 Mar 30  2017 iwlwifi-7265-10.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  880604 Mar 30  2017 iwlwifi-7265-12.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  885224 Mar 30  2017 iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1180224 Oct 17 21:10 iwlwifi-7265-14.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1180356 Mar 30  2017 iwlwifi-7265-16.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1180412 Oct  8 21:54 iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  690452 Mar 30  2017 iwlwifi-7265-8.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  697828 Mar 30  2017 iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      21 Nov 17  2017 iwlwifi-7265D-10.ucode -> iwlwifi-7265-10.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1002800 Mar 30  2017 iwlwifi-7265D-12.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1008692 Mar 30  2017 iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1384256 Oct 17 21:10 iwlwifi-7265D-14.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1384500 Mar 30  2017 iwlwifi-7265D-16.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1383604 Nov 17  2017 iwlwifi-7265D-17.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1385368 Nov 17  2017 iwlwifi-7265D-21.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1028376 Apr 24  2018 iwlwifi-7265D-22.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1032740 Dec  5  2017 iwlwifi-7265D-27.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1036668 Oct  8 21:54 iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue here. If, as you say, "The WiFi works though", then what is the issue? Did you manually install a driver? Why? The ucode files you refer to above are firmware files, not drivers. The correct driver, *iwlwifi*, is clearly being used.

Comment: I am curious why in UI it says _Device not working_.

Comment: It appears that you compiled the *iwlwifi* driver from backports. After you upgraded to 19.10, backports didn’t build correctly via dkms for the 5.3.0-xx kernel. The normal, inbuilt driver *iwlwifi* correctly drives your device.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the results of the terminal command: `sudo dkms status`

Comment: I filed an official bug - hopefully we can resolve this problem together with Canonical: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/backport-iwlwifi-dkms/+bug/1849891

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem after updating from Ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10. It seems that before the update process, we both probably had the package "backport-iwlwifi-dkms" installed, either manually or automatically. That package compiled a driver for the specific version kernel you were on. Although it may have mostly worked after the update, the Additional Drivers tool identified a compatibility mismatch with the new kernel.

The solution for me was quite simple: reinstall backport-iwlwifi-dkms with the following command. There was no need to disable 802.11n or anything else!

```
sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms
```

After the installation finishes, close the Additional Drivers window and reopen it. The window should now look like this.

[image: The window should now look like this]

Answer (score 6):

**Update**: In my case WIFI works again after disabling 802.11n. I added the option `11n_disable=1` to `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` - now it looks like this:

```
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac8021
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

See also https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_configuration/Wireless#iwlwifi (the iwlwifi parameters apply to Ubuntu too and Arch has great documentation )

---

I have the exact same problem (no WIFI connections after upgrade to Ubuntu MATE 19.10) and the exact same WIFI card (same output of lspci).

The problem is also present for new installs of Ubuntu MATE and has nothing to do with the upgrade - I tried with the Ubuntu Mate 18.10 and Kubuntu 19.10 on a USB stick: same behavior. So I would say all Ubuntu 19.10 flavors are affected.

I want to elaborate on the what's not working part:

- WIFI is active, and I can see available networks, e.g. with `iwlist wlp3s0 scan`
- However, connecting to a network (with the GUI) fails: after entering credentials (for a password protrected WPA2 network) it tries to connect for a few seconds but then asks for a passphrase again .. and again ..
- Also the problem is not the GUI, the exact same behavior is shown by `nmtui`

Checking the output of NetworkManager in `/var/log/syslog` we can see that the **association** is the one that fails:

`sudo cat /var/log/syslog  | grep "(wlp3s0)" | sed 's/.*device //'`

```
device (wlp3s0): Activation: starting connection 'MY_WIFI' (c5c790fb-86a8-4905-97b0-75170f5e985c)
device (wlp3s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'MY_WIFI' has security, but secrets are required.
device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
device (wlp3s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'MY_WIFI' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: ready -> scanning
device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long
device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) asking for new secrets
device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
device (wlp3s0): no secrets: User canceled the secrets request.
device (wlp3s0): state change: need-auth -> failed (reason 'no-secrets', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
device (wlp3s0): Activation: failed for connection 'MY_WIFI'
device (wlp3s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

This is what the log looked like before the update with Ubuntu MATE 19.04

```
device (wlp3s0): Activation: starting connection 'MY_WLAN' (b3dffdda-2b7b-467d-a1f5-2b3077d26eb3)
device (wlp3s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'MY_WLAN' has security, but secrets are required.
device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed') 
device (wlp3s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'MY_WLAN' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed. 
device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: ready -> authenticating
device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "MY_WLAN"
device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed') 
dhcp4 (wlp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
dhcp4 (wlp3s0): dhclient started with pid 20140
dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   address 192.168.1.161
dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   gateway 192.168.1.1
dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   lease time 43200
dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   hostname 'whakaari'
dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   nameserver '192.168.1.1'
dhcp4 (wlp3s0): state changed unknown -> bound
device (wlp3s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
device (wlp3s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
device (wlp3s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
policy: set 'MY_WLAN' (wlp3s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS 
device (wlp3s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
```

Checking the journal and logs I can not find any errors or warnings, but I noted that iwlwifi seems to have a debug mode activated.

`sudo journalctl | grep iwlwifi` for Ubuntu 19.04:

```
Sep 10 19:59:56 whakaari kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.1044073957.0 op_mode iwlmvm
Sep 10 19:59:56 whakaari kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
Sep 10 19:59:56 whakaari kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: base HW address: 5c:e0:c5:63:e2:a5
Sep 10 19:59:57 whakaari kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
Sep 10 19:59:57 whakaari sensors[873]: iwlwifi-virtual-0
Sep 10 19:59:58 whakaari NetworkManager[856]: <info>  [1568138398.2497] rfkill3: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:03:00.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill3) (driver iwlwifi)
```

`sudo journalctl | grep iwlwifi` for Ubuntu 19.10:

```
Oct 19 16:16:30 whakaari kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
Oct 19 16:16:30 whakaari kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
Oct 19 16:16:30 whakaari kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.1654887522.0 op_mode iwlmvm
Oct 19 16:16:30 whakaari kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
Oct 19 16:16:30 whakaari kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
Oct 19 16:16:30 whakaari kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
Oct 19 16:16:30 whakaari kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: base HW address: 5c:e0:c5:63:e2:a5
Oct 19 16:16:31 whakaari kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
Oct 19 16:16:32 whakaari sensors[941]: iwlwifi-virtual-0
```

Comment: Having the same issue with a Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7260, REV=0x144

Comment: Also seeing same issue on Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8265, REV=0x230. PopOS update screen suggested the backports driver update, which I'm not really sure why I installed, since this card is already supported in kernel anyway. But backports shouldnt be breaking already supported cards.

Comment: I am on a fresh 19.10 install and WiFi worked fine until an update a couple of days ago. What I do not understand is why we all of sudden need a DKMS loaded driver. That was not the case when I installed 19.10.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem after the upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04.1. Here it looked slightly different; maybe this helps:

```
rfkill list all
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 59)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:9010]
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

So it is not active. Following the first answer as above:

```
$ sudo dkms status
acpi-call/1.2.2, 5.15.0-53-generic, x86_64: installed
acpi-call/1.2.2, 5.4.0-132-generic, x86_64: installed
backport-iwlwifi/9858, 5.15.0-53-generic, x86_64: installed
backport-iwlwifi/9858, 5.4.0-132-generic, x86_64: installed
evdi/1.7.0, 5.4.0-132-generic, x86_64: installed
evdi/5.2.14: added
```

obviously not correct. Therefore trying to install it:

```
[...]
backport-iwlwifi-dkms is already the newest version (9858-0ubuntu3.1).
```

Seems to serve no purpose,however,so uninstall:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge backport-iwlwifi-dkms
[...]
iwlwifi.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.15.0-53-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

[...]
Deleting module backport-iwlwifi-9858 completely from the DKMS tree.
```

Same here:

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 59)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:9010]
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Why not trying this?:

```
$ sudo modprobe iwlwifi
$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 59)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:9010]
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
$
```

Here we are, up and running.

I don't see much logic in this; do we need the dkms; or is the driver 'just there'?