# Upgraded to 19.10 and now wireless networks aren't detected (Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260)

Tags: networking, drivers, upgrade, 19.10

Not totally sure where to look for clues to what's going on. In the GUI, it appears that the wifi is searching for a network, but nothing ever appears.

Output of `lspci` is

```
Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260 (rev 29)
```

Last of `dmesg | grep iwlwifi` is

```
[  719.324454] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[  719.324456] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Status: 0x00000100, count: 7
[  719.324458] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x20000034 | NMI_INTERRUPT_WDG
[  719.324460] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[  719.324462] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xC008888E | umac branchlink2
[  719.324464] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xC0084C80 | umac interruptlink1
[  719.324466] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xC0080708 | umac interruptlink2
[  719.324468] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000400 | umac data1
[  719.324469] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xC0080708 | umac data2
[  719.324471] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
[  719.324473] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0000002E | umac major
[  719.324475] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x6BF1DF06 | umac minor
[  719.324477] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0003D177 | frame pointer
[  719.324479] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xC0886C44 | stack pointer
[  719.324480] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00230405 | last host cmd
[  719.324482] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00004008 | isr status reg
[  719.324573] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FW error in SYNC CMD GEO_TX_POWER_LIMIT
[  719.324617]  iwl_trans_pcie_send_hcmd+0x521/0x540 [iwlwifi]
[  719.324641]  iwl_trans_send_cmd+0x71/0xe0 [iwlwifi]
[  719.324678]  ? iwl_acpi_get_object+0xbc/0x130 [iwlwifi]
[  719.325072] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Collecting data: trigger 2 fired.
[  719.325090] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Firmware not running - cannot dump error
```

`uname -r` is `4.15.0-1059-oem`

Everything was working fine before the upgrade.

Update: After restarting things have gotten worse! Now I get "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found" in the wi-fi settings and there's no output from `dmesg | grep iwlwifi` at all.

Comment: What make and model of computer do you have?

Comment: A Dell XPS 13; this year's model

Comment: I have the same problem: `07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:24fd] (rev 78)`. Here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181844/wifi-disabled-ubuntu-19-10-intel-wireless-7265/1182338 the same but for model `7265`

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I have experienced this problem with all 5.3+ kernels.

Comment: I am still not sure what happened. I needed wifi so I reinstalled the Dell version of 18.04 and I'm not planning to upgrade. I noticed that my kernel didn't update from 4.15.0 when I installed 19.10, so my best guess is that there were pieces of 19.10 that expected a newer kernel.