# Bluetooth not working Lenovo laptop - Ubuntu 19.10 (but it did in LiveCD)

Tags: bluetooth, 19.10

Edit: The solution in [Wifi-Disabled: Ubuntu 19.10 - Intel Wireless 7265](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181844/wifi-disabled-ubuntu-19-10-intel-wireless-7265) worked for me.

```
sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms
```

---

I am aware there are lots of other people complaining about this, so there must be something.
I booted my Lenovo Yoga 900 with an Ubuntu 19.10 Live USB and I could connect my Bluetooth mouse without any problem.
I installed the OS and Bluetooth worked no more. The switch ON/OFF moved, but no device discovery appeared to be running.

See the attached images. There is the Intel device firmware, and some commands to show additional info.

[image: hciconfig]
[image: dmesg]
[image: bluetooth_status]