Activation of network connection failed 24.04
I recently updated my Ubuntu from 24.04 to 24.04.1 in the middle of nowhere it stopped updating and showed some error, now I can't use the internet on my laptop from Wifi and ethernet it shows (Connection failed, activation of network failed ),I am to use mobile hotspot it works fine, but from the router not possible, tried everything from watching youtube, GPT, etc nothing works any help will be appreciated, I don't want to reset my laptop!!
 sudo lshw -C network*-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Ethernet Connection (3) I218-LM
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 19
   bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
   logical name: eno1
   version: 03
   serial: 84:7b:eb:04:4b:56
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=6.8.0-45-generic firmware=0.2-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:56 memory:f7200000-f721ffff memory:f7243000-f7243fff ioport:f080(size=32) network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless 7265
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlp2s0
   version: 59
   serial: 10:02:b5:9d:1c:2d
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=6.8.0-45-generic firmware=29.4063824552.0 7265D-29.ucode latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:54 memory:f7000000-f7001fff
sudo nmcli devicestatus   
DEVICE    TYPE      STATE                    CONNECTION  
wlp2s0   wifi      connecting (getting IP confg)  Mohan       
lo      loopback   connected (externally)         lo 
docker0  bridge    connected (externally)      docker0
p2p-dev-wlp2s0  wifi-p2p  disconnected            --
eno1     ethernet  unavailable                    --

solution worked for me
o correct the issue with nm-dhcp-helper being blocked by AppArmor and possibly interfering with your Wi-Fi connection, follow these steps:
Step 1: Set AppArmor to "complain mode" for nm-dhcp-helper
This will allow nm-dhcp-helper to run without restrictions while still logging potential security issues. It's a good way to troubleshoot whether AppArmor is causing the issue.
Run the following command to set nm-dhcp-helper into complain mode:
bash
Copy code
sudo aa-complain /usr/libexec/nm-dhcp-helper
This will make AppArmor allow actions that it would otherwise block, but still log them for later analysis.
Restart the network services to apply changes:
bash
Copy code
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
Check if the Wi-Fi now connects successfully and if the DHCP issue is resolved. You can monitor logs with:
bash
Copy code
sudo journalctl -f | grep NetworkManager

Please append to your answer the output of the following commends: 'sudo lshw -C network' & ;dkms status'   & 'sudo nmcli device status'

added everything on my question and dkms status is not installed, do I need to install and configure it? @david

if dkms is not installed that is fine. What does 'Software Updates->Additional drivers report? Take a look at the following link answers and see if it is of any help. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181844/wifi-disabled-ubuntu-19-10-intel-wireless-7265

If the computer has access to the internet via mobile hotspot but not through your router, this implies the problem is with your router and not Ubuntu. I would check your router and start troubleshooting that.

@mpboden , I check with multiple wifi routers its the problem on my laptop

@david tried running sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms is not showing any additional drivers, tried some about kernel and generic version removal and update not working  ,  so now trying about disabling 802.11n, let see how it goes

found a solution , added into a question itself, thanks for the support @david
